# my tmux status bar has disappeared

Tags: session, tmux

While writing code inside a tmux session, I inadvertently pressed a sequence of keys that has made my status bar disappear.

I haven't touched my tmux config file, and I verified the status bar is visible in new tmux sessions. Disconnecting and reconnecting to this session didn't help.

Read through the man page and searched through Google, no luck so far.

Running the following commands from inside the session didn't help:
 ^B :set-option -g status-bg default
 ^B :set-option -g status on

I have many windows open and would prefer not to have to destroy this session.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you cannot restore the status bar, you should be able to create a new session which shares all the windows with the old session, then kill the old session.

Comment: If you mean attaching to the session from another terminal, I tried that with `tmux attach`.  I successfully attached to the same session from a different terminal, but still no status bar.  If you meant something different, could you please provide a sample command? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the tmux command line, issue:

```
:set status on
```

to turn the status bar on. You can simplify this by adding a line to your `.tmux.conf`:

```
# toggle statusbar
bind-key b set-option status
```

and then reload your config.

Comment: that did it, thanks!  I went back to the man page and there it is...not sure how I missed it.  thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite a solution, but a possible workaround.

I'll assume your old session is number 0; adjust the argument to `-t` as necessary.

```
tmux new-session -t 0
```

This creates a new session which has all the same windows as session 0. If you create a new window in one session, it appears in the other as well. If you delete a window from one, it is removed from the other. More importantly, the new session should have a status bar. Then, you can try removing the old status-free session:

```
tmux kill-session -t 0
```

This should not affect the windows in session 0, since they are all part of your new session as well.

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that, thanks for the tip.  The answer by @jasonwryan worked.